# Windows Phone 8.1, How to bind style to view?

Tags: wpf, binding, resources, styles, windows-phone-8.1

I wrote a style for button. Unfortunately, I encountered a problem: font size of the button depends on a value, which I can compute **only** in the view (specifically, that's `DisplayInformation` stuff).

Ideally, I would do the following:

```
<Style x:key="MyStyle" BasedOn="{StaticResource SomeStyle}" TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{Binding ElementName=rootControl, Path=SomeProperty" />
</Style>
```

Then, I would simply provide necessary properties in view class. But that simply doesn't work (does nothing, no messages, no errors).

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assigning a binding to a setter value is not supported in the Windows Runtime. (It might be supported in WPF and Silverlight 5, however).

If you google around, there are workarounds, but they're kind of hacky. See [this](http://aventuraspuntonet.wordpress.com/2014/02/13/mixing-style-setters-and-bindings-in-winrt/), which uses attached properties and a binding helper class.